# how to select JSX tag in my css stylesheet

Tags: css

how would I select my `<Link to>` tag in my css file.

```
<nav>
   <Link to='/'>Landing</Link>
   <Link to='/library'>Library</Link>
   <Link to='/album'>Album</Link>
</nav>

header nav Link to:hover{
  background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure React Link renders an anchor.  All you need to do is style the anchor tag.  You're trying to style the JSX markup, which is not what is ultimately rendered.

Comment: I forgot that little detail, and you're right it is the anchor tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `<Link to='/'>Landing</Link>` element is a `react-router-dom` component it will became `<a href="/">Landing<a>` (you can check it in browser developer tools).

In your case, you need:

```
header nav a:hover{
    background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: ahh checking the element in the browser is a useful method, thanks for the tip!